# php random mixed alpha cases

Tags: php, string

I would to see another way to convert some of the character in the string to mixed case i think my way is not the optimal way..

```
$arr_str = str_split("w2abcd");

$atCase = "";
foreach ($arr_str as $cha) {
    $toup =  rand(0, 1);

    if($toup == 1){ $atCase .= ucfirst($cha); } else { $atCase .=  $cha;}
}
    $rtnstr = $atCase;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks pretty good. the optimization may be like this:

```
$str = "w2abcd";
for ($i=0,$c=strlen($str);$i<$c;$i++)
  $str[$i] = rand(0, 100) > 50?$strtoupper($str[$i]):$str[$i];
return $str;
```

Comment: i have found your way to be slightly faster when calling but for higher calls like 1000+ array str_split is faster.

Comment: @david what do you use to check speed?

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi i some times use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919543/php-codes-performance-test#answer-2919589 and (ab) apache benchmark tool

Answer (score 2):

Well, just my variant:

```
<?php
$str = str_split(strtolower('some text'));
foreach ($str as &$char)
{
    if (rand(0, 1)) $char = strtoupper($char);
}
print implode('', $str);
```