# Performance: file_get_contents(), Relative and Absolute URLs

Tags: php

Is there any performance advantage if I use relative paths as argument in `file_get_contents()`?

`file_get_contents("../../mypage.php");`

**v/s**

`file_get_contents("http://.../mypage.php");`

How is `file_get_contents()` handled internally?

Comment: It depends on how many include paths your application has and files located within. But probably not... most-likely a micro-optimization.

Comment: Your two examples show two different wrappers - The first is local filesystem, the second is HTTP.

Comment: Surely one would get handled by PHP and the other wouldn't?? I mean one would be parsed and the other wouldn't.

Comment: Maybe try both methods and test performances.
==>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919543/php-codes-performance-test
Let us know the results, it interests me :)

Comment: @Pete I wanted to know if optimization is done such that **2.** does go through DNS resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a performance advantage, it does not depend on php engine. Paths are processed by the web server you query.

But in this case there is going to be a performance advantage in the first case because you get the file from local fs, and in the second case you have to go through the whole network stack(http/tcp/ip) to get the response. Also first case will return php source and the second - a web page, processed by the php engine.

A clearer example:

```
file_get_contents('../../somefile.ext');
```

and

```
file_get_contents('/home/user/somefile.ext');
```

are going to be equally fast.

Answer (score 6):

There can definitely be a noticeable performance difference in using local files versus remote - even if the "remote" file is on your local server.

When you use a local/relative file such as `file_get_contents("../../mypage.php");`, it's loaded directly on the server with no need to use network traffic. For remote loads, such as `file_get_contents("http://localhost/mypage.php");` or `file_get_contents("http://example.org/mypage.php");`, a connection to the remote host is established (even when "local"). Additionally, a local read will result in the function returning exactly what's in the file; a remote read will result in the remote-host rendering the contents (if it's PHP) before returning.

The performance for a local/relative file would, by default, be faster than a remote one. The biggest noticeable performance advantage can be seen when attempting to load a remote file from a network that has a slower connection.

The internal implementation of `file_get_contents()` is similar to you writing `fopen()` and a loop for `fread()`, and then closing with `fclose()`. Then, it returns a string of all of the contents found in the file. Basically, it provides a much friendlier "read from a file" interface.

To read more about the method, you can check out the manual at [php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)