# PHP/GD : Better Gaussian blur

Tags: php, gd, blur, imagefilter

I want to blur an image with GD library, unfortunately the GAUSSIAN_BLUR effect that GD gives isn't enough and i want something being more *blurrish*

```
<?php $im = imagecreatefrompng($_GET['image']);
if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR))
{
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
}
else
{
    echo 'fail';
}

imagedestroy($im);
```

I want something like this or at least near it.
[image: image from //tutorial9.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2008/06/lens-blur.jpg]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try convolution:

```
$gaussian = array(array(1.0, 2.0, 1.0), array(2.0, 4.0, 2.0), array(1.0, 2.0, 1.0));
imageconvolution($image, $gaussian, 16, 0);
```

`$gaussian` is a matrix, so mathematically it's

```
[[1, 2, 1],
 [2, 4, 2],
 [1, 2, 1]]
```

you can find other convolution filters at: http://aishack.in/tutorials/image-convolution-examples/

```
imageconvolution( <image element>, <convolution matrix>, <divisor (sum of convolution matrix)>, <color offset>);
```

so from the code above `1+2+1+2+4+2+1+2+1 = 16` the sum of the matrix. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php#97921 is a neat trick for getting the 
sum of the divisor.

check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php for more info on this function.

good ol' fashion blur is (1,2,1),(2,1,2),(1,2,1)

**EDIT:**
[as stated below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642155/276250) you can run any filter more than once on the resulting output to also enhance the effect.

Comment: not near to what i want but thanks, any other way to blur it more ?? EDIT : sorry didn't read your edit, looking into the examples, thanks !

Comment: seems like this matrix : array(2.0, 3.0, 2.0), array(3.0, 6.0, 3.0), array(2.0, 3.0, 2.0) is the biggest matrix this function can read, i've read that 5x5 matrices can do better and stronger blur, any ideas ?

Comment: using the function several times gave the result i want, yet it is not the best solution out there *for sure*

Comment: not sure why PHP wouldn't allow bigger matrices, might be a GD limitation I know IMagick takes 5x5's ... If you have adobe photoshop using filter>custom lets you play with convolution.

Comment: ImageMagick isn't a good option compared to GD,GD is almost installed in every server, unlike ImageMagick....Any options to evade the function repitition ??

Answer (score 20):

After coming across the same problem, I applied the same filter a few times, and each time to the resulting resource of the previous "imagefilter" call. I got the 'more blurry' effect you're looking for.

e.g.:

```
for ($x=1; $x<=15; $x++)
   imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
```

Comment: I've used it myself, so I can assure you it works as expected.

Comment: I have used this, but this is unbearably slow.

Comment: it's slow but I still use it

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php
//
//fastblur function from image hosting and processing site http://hero-in.com
//

function blur($img, $radius=10)
{

if ($radius>100) $radius=100; //max radius
if ($radius<0) $radius=0; //nin radius

$radius=$radius*4;
$alphaStep=round(100/$radius)*1.7;
$width=imagesx($img);
$height=imagesy($img);
$beginX=floor($radius/2);
$beginY=floor($radius/2);


//make clean imahe sample for multiply
$cleanImageSample=imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopy($cleanImageSample, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);


//make h blur
for($i = 1; $i < $radius+1; $i++)
{
$xPoint=($beginX*-1)+$i-1;
imagecopymerge($img, $cleanImageSample, $xPoint, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $alphaStep);
}
//make v blur
imagecopy($cleanImageSample, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
for($i = 1; $i < $radius+1; $i++)
{
$yPoint=($beginY*-1)+$i-1;
imagecopymerge($img, $cleanImageSample, 0, $yPoint, 0, 0, $width, $height, $alphaStep);
}
//finish
return $img;
imagedestroy($cleanImageSample); 
}

//example
$im = ImageCreateFromJpeg('image.jpg');
$im = blur($im,10);
imagejpeg($im)
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have very good result with following code based on [this](http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/12/09/php-image-blur.html) solution:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) {
        if ($i % 10 == 0) {//each 10th time apply 'IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH' with 'level of smoothness' set to -7
            imagefilter($tmp_dst_image, IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH, -7);
        }
        imagefilter($tmp_dst_image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
    }
```

When you apply smooth after several blurs it delivers very good blurry effect. You can experiment with the following number in the code: `25, 10, -7`.

**See also:** [How to measure the speed of code written in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202746)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the imagefilter arguments help but check them out.

Alternatively, simply apply the image filter to it's result a couple of times???

Answer (score 1):

For better speed use https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.imagick-gaussianblurimage.php

Note: You need to install `Imagick` php extention (follow install instructions from [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/645/how-to-install-imagick-for-php-7-in-ubuntu-16-04)

example

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = new Imagick('https://i.dr.com.tr/cache/600x600-0/originals/0000000671636-1.jpg');

// Use gaussianBlurImage function 
$image->gaussianBlurImage(7, 5);

// Display the output image 
echo $image;
```