# How to achieve a blur effect in PHP?

Tags: php, gd

I've been looking for PHP code to apply a Gaussian blur to images.

What I've done was like this:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('new.jpg'); 
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
imagejpeg($image, 'blur.jpeg');
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

However the effect is very weak, and if I repeat the blur effect, it takes a very long time to process and the end result is still not that good.

I also used Timthumb , I always liked its simplicity, but it crops the image by default and its blurring effect is very weak.

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245710/php-gd-better-gaussian-blur

Comment: Command-line or PHP module _ImageMagick_ can do this - any decent algorithm should be able to take a blur value. Did you do a search for this, and if so what did it turn up?

Comment: @ErikNedwidek , it feels a bit complicated to make this calcualtions as I want to connect the blur value to a slider so the user can easily change the blur effect.
Also it needs the same strategy .. repeat the code to get a stronger effect

Comment: @halfer I think ImageMagick is not present on all servers, so that can be a source of pain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ImageMagic

**Original Image**

[image]

Run via `exec`

```
convert a.png -blur 0x3 a_blur.png
```

**[image: Output]**

OR Run

```
convert a.png -blur 0x8 a_blur.png
```

[image]

Comment: wow ! the effect looks great ! after some searching, I found that it's present also as a plugin for Wordpress ! I guess I will take a closer look at it ..Thank u

Answer (score 7):

It is possible also without ImageMagic lib;

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$blurs = 10;
$image = imagecreatefrompng('blur.png');
for ($i = 0; $i < $blurs; $i++) {
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
}
imagepng($image, 'blur10.png');
imagedestroy($image);
```

After 10 blur applied;

[image]

Comment: Thank u, but this method takes a longer time to be done & increasing the blur value to higher degrees makes it distorted, not well blurred like Baba's third example.

Comment: @kerem: I used ur code and it work nice..but I am unable to save it in image folder.could u plz provide code to save generated blur code?

Comment: got solution to my query.I used  imagepng("image name","target"); to save image.

Answer (score 0):

Image optimization is very heavy process so personally if i have these kind of task in PHP then i use this PHP Image Library Called [PhpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) it can create blur images without any code you just need to call it's script via url and provide  parameters according to its docs check it's [demo](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php).