# pixel level processing of image

Tags: javascript, css, image, web

I have a image, i want to show it blurred and as the users buy things on the website, the image gets clearer.

Can anyone suggest how can I make the image blurred and make the pixels clear everytime a users buys something?

Comment: Have two images, one blurred and one non-blurred and just replace the `src=''` attribute?

Comment: you should use `canvas` to process your image and put a filer like blur on it. There are plenty of such questions on stackoverflow already asked.

Comment: You can use the `<canvas>` element for that. But beware that only the latest versions of all browsers support the `<canvas>` element. So ppl using old browsers like IE7,8 will not be able to see your image.

Comment: you can use css filters to blur in decent browsers, but you can also stack 10 of the same images atop each other but offset a pixel or two here and there, each one at 10% opacity. remove one at a time and update opacity to 1/# of images. when you get to 1 image at 100% opacity, there will be no blur left.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it server side, because I think you really want them to buy those things before seeing the image. If your server exposes the image, and you process it client side, everyone will be able to see the image, with little effort. Take a look at the PHP  graphical libraries.

A similar stackoverflow question: [How to achieve a blur effect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428257/how-to-achieve-a-blur-effect-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The new simple answer to this is to add a CSS filter to your image:

```
filter: blur(5px);
```

If you want more or less blurring under JavaScript control, then just vary the number of px in the blur.

##### Original Answer:

This webpage: http://creativejs.com/2011/12/day-5-blur-that-canvas/
has a bunch of examples of blurring an image in canvas.  As the user buys things, you can re-blur the original image with a lower amount of blur.

Comment: This link no longer works