# Blur out images for different account levels with PHP, CSS, JavaScript or any means possible

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am building a membership site and I don't want free members to see other members pictures clearly. The premium users will be able to see all images clearly. I was partially able to achieve this using css and svg filter but the downside is that when a user clik+hold+drag an image, the normal image is shown and too, a free member can easily download the image and get the clear copy.

I have thought of converting all image SRC into background-image using jQuery. But I can't find a way to limit this script to just a particular div. This is the code I used to convert image src into background:

```
$("img").each(function(i, elem) {
   var img = $(elem);
   var div = $("<div />").css({
   background: "url(" + img.attr("src") + ") no-repeat",
   width: img.width() + "px",
   height: img.height() + "px"
});
   img.replaceWith(div);
});
```

I will really appreciate if I can find another solution outside the jQuery one because the jQuery is conflicting with other features on the site.

Please I need a solution for this in anyway possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: blurring should probably be done server side to prevent any possibility of script disablement or style sheet modification revealing images

Comment: $('yourContainerSelector').find("img").each ... won't do it? Anyway, you can also download a background-image. So to be sure, you'll need to modify the images server side. What do you use? PHP?

Comment: If you don't want users to be able to see the images, don't send the images to the user. This means manipulating them on the server first. If the unblurred images get sent from the server, there's always a way that someone will be able to download them. Always.

Comment: @axel.michel Yes, I use PHP.

Comment: Plenty of other questions on php image manipulation to help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7245710/3651800

Comment: @dspacedude http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagefilter.php - there is a ready to use blur filter in PHP - have a look. You'll also find a few examples to start with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a common class on each image
as your dummy class for making dull images.
then you don't need a loop.

or you can use css property 'opacity'
for making images dull.
i hope this will help you :)

Comment: Note however that someone just needs to turn off your style-sheet in browser and boom! the unregistered user can see all your user photos. Hence the need to perform this server-side... probably do it once at the time the user submits their photo to the site.

Comment: yes it is. you have to make different  type images with different quality on server side.