# PHP - Is there better/smarter way for blur image?

Tags: php, gd, blur, imagefilter

I use gaussian blur. 1 line of

```
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
```

doesn't give the desired blur intensity. So I need to use it like 30 times. This is an unprofessional way, it increases the page load time a lot when there are many images on the page. So is there any better/smarter way for image blur ?

```
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("caski_m.jpg");
  imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
  header("content-type: image/jpeg");
  imagepng($image);
  imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245710/php-gd-better-gaussian-blur. The default gaussian blur has no control of the blurring, you need to make your own....

Comment: did u try IMG_FILTER_SELECTIVE_BLUR

Comment: it seems to be a duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching more concise and elegant solution then:

1. install `ImageMagick` extension for `php`
2. use php `exec` command to invoke ImageMagick convert operator:

Schema: `exec("convert <your_image_name> -blur <blur_level> <your_blured_image_name> ");`
You can adjust blur level flexibly.
Example: `exec("convert '$image' -blur 0x8 'blur_' . $image");`
But don't forget to specify accesible image path.
To get more options look at the following: [imagick_blur_guide](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur)