# What is the modern way to blur an image with PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick, imagefilter

I want to blur images dynamically, but it has to be a very strong blur, so it can only be assumed what the real image is.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245710/php-gd-better-gaussian-blur?rq=1) where `imagefilter` is used. But this solution didn't blur my image enough.

1. Somewhere I also read that it's too old and not modern anymore to use Imagick. Is this true? What is the best method in the modern standards of 2016/2017 or is even a good php class out there?
2. If I'm using Imagick [like in this example on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.blurimage.php) do I have to include a file with this image header to display one or more images on a webpage or is there a way to use Imagick without setting an image header?

Comment: why dont you use JS

Comment: In the question you posted, the second answer (and most upvoted) specifically says you can apply the filter more than once. Have you tried that?

Comment: You should add your code

Comment: Jonathan: Yes, I tried it. Still not blurry as I need it. Machavity: I have a similiar code as I stated the linked question used as accepted answer. But I need to know the best option first for my specific desired result. Shailesh: I don't want to use JS, because I want to cache the image on the server.

Comment: To the one who voted to close this question: How is this not about programming? What would be the purpose of posting my code if it doesn't help to solve my issue at all and is in the accepted answer in the question I linked? Some people should read first.

Comment: @Vay: I hate these people too. They really ruin StackOverflow. I don't see any flaws in your question and hope someone will help you soon.

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
for ($x=1; $x<=15; $x++)
{
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I already said that I tried that code and the result isnt blurry enough, no matter how many loops will process the image.