# PHP slowdown, but where

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that loads and orders about 130 results from a mysql query into a HTML table. PHPmyadmin does this in 0.003 seconds, but my page takes 0.5 seconds. Somewhere the php code is slow, but I suck at debugging it.

One thing I did to speed up performance is that I found something like

```
if($var == '123'){ //action }
```

while $var did not exist. By changing it to

```
if(isset($var)){
  if($var =='123'){
    //action
  }
}
```

the script became much faster when $var was not around.

My question: what is the best way to find out the slowdown in my script? Are there more things like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200214/how-can-i-measure-the-speed-of-code-written-in-php this may help you to find your slow code

Comment: It may be faster but it's not doing the same thing.  `=` is not the same thing as `==`.

Comment: `if($var ='123')` is not a check, it's value assigning

Comment: Sorry, = should be ==, typo. I meant that adding isset() speeds it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't have made much difference to the performance unless there is somethng very strange about your code / config you've not told us about. Try running your code through a profiler. (I use xdebug + kcachegrind - but you didn't say what OS you are using).

How do you get your page load times? PMA does't normally show a full result set. 0.003 seconds seems a bit optimistic. Not sure I trust your analysis. But certainly 0.5 seconds is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

How do you return the results? `echo`ing within a loop may cause some performance issues, it's a very expensive instruction. If you do, change your implementation to something like this:

```
$resultOutput = '';

foreach($result as $var)
{
    // to seize AbsoluteZERO's idea
    switch ($var)
    {
        case "456":
        //do something
        $resultOutput .= '\n456 found';
        break;

        case "123":
        //do something
        $resultOutput .= '\n123 found';
        break;

        default:
        //give them an error or something
    }
}

echo $resultOutput;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `&&` (and) [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) instead of the nested if:

```
if(!empty($var)&&($var=='123')){
    //action
}
```

If you're checking for multiple values with [loose comparisons](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) `==`, instead of a nested `if` you can use a [`switch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
if(!empty($var)){
  switch ($var){

   case "456":
   //do something      
   break;

   case "123":
   //do something
   break;

   default:
   //give them an error or something

  }
}
```