# Measure PHP code performance

Tags: php, asp.net, performance

I have used Dot net & PHP both. In Visual Studio, for check code effeciency, i use breakpoint. Suppose, I want to check which part of the code is taking more time in execution, I put the breakpoint in two places & check the time taken to reach 2nd breakpoint from 1st breakpoint. This way, I check for every part of my code which is taking more time in execution.

Is there any same way in PHP, in which I can measure my PHP script's performance for every part of the code ? or is there any ready made tool available like visual studio to measure it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200214/how-can-i-measure-the-speed-of-code-written-in-php