# Time need to run preg_match_all() with 30000 pattern words

Tags: php, performance

I need to match `\u1000` to `\u102F`.

This is Myanmar letters.

Someone post me Myanmar text.

Its `strlen()` is about 50 to 120.

Then my server do `preg_match_all()` it with 30,000 patterns.

Server that I will buy is 1Gb ram and 1 CPU(2.33GHz).

How much time take my server do once completed `preg_match_all()` to this text?

I have some ploblem to scale server.

I know 
    $start=microtime();
    code
    echo microtime()-$start;

Please help me if someone tested it or do it.To scale up server.I'm student.In my country,toping up paypal is so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative without making any code changes. Do you have root access to the server? If so install an Application Performance Monitoring (APM) tool. You can either install Newrelic or AppDynamics. Both have a trial/free version.

I've used both and they are both good products. After you install and get your app/server info reported in either of these product dashboards, just run your .php script and you will be able to see the execution of that method time along with the resources (CPU/Memory) it takes.

Good luck!

**Update**
This was closed as duplicate where the question was asked to find a software that can  measure performance so I replied here as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33152363/3007014

Comment: You're welcome! Happy perf measuring.