# How this ... operator works in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

On my everyday office work, I have to deal with different types of multidimensional array and sometime I flat them to single dimension for my work purpose. Most of the time I prefer **call_user_func_array** with with **array_merge** param. Actually I want to know how they internally work specially the `...` operator way and which method is faster?

```
<?php
$data = [[1, 2], [3], [4, 5]];
print '<pre>';
print_r(array_merge(... $data)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
print_r(call_user_func_array('array_merge',$data)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
print_r(array_reduce($data, 'array_merge', []));   // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Comment: You can read about [variadic function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) in the PHP documentation. They're available since 5.6

Comment: @DarraghEnright thnx for the ref. Actually I was unable to find the word to google it.

Comment: No problem :) Yeah, I've had some trouble finding it in the past before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually I want to know how they internally work

The [documentation for variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) may give you some info. I won't link the documentation for the other functions you've mentioned as they are easy to google.

I don't know how they work internally, but you could dig through the [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src) to find out. Bear in mind that it is written in C.

> which method is faster?

Check out [this answer on measuring performance of PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202746/4878850). TLDR: Measure microtime, or use [xdebug's profiling tool](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).