# Is it more efficient to make only one query and store it in an array or make a query every time?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'd like to know what is more efficient, make just one query and store the result in an array and then check this array using the function in_array from PHP or make a MySQL query every time I need to check the value?

For example:
I created this function to store the query in a array, so this query will be made just one time.

```php
 private function carregaPermissoes(){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT permissao_nome FROM sisgrupopermissoes WHERE id_grupo = ".$this->getGid().";");
        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
            $array_permissoes = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                array_push($array_permissoes, $row["permissao_nome"]);
            }
            return $array_permissoes;
        }
    }
```

Then every time I need to check it I just use this function:

```php
public function checkPermissao($permissao){
        $this->setPermissao($permissao);
        if (in_array($this->getPermissao(), $this->getGrupoPermissao())){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is it a good way to do it? Or is better make a query every time I need to check it?

Comment: Generally, unless you need up-to-date information, the fewer round trips to the database, the better. Note that you are using an archaic, insecure, and deprecated API.

Comment: Agreed with @Strawberry. If you want to find out for sure in a specific case, write it both ways, and measure the performance. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202746/350538

Answer (score 1):

SQL queries are **slow**, typically the most common bottleneck after the
network. Your function could be simplified into:

```
public function checkPermissao($permissao)
{
    // The following line smells...
    $this->setPermissao($permissao);
    return in_array($this->getPermissao(), $this->getGrupoPermissao());
}
```

If you are afraid of the overhead introduced by `in_array` (that intrinsically uses a sequential search) you can [flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) the haystack array and use [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the permission in an array and checking inside. What if someone/admin change the permission, at this time you have the old permission in your array, as per my understanding this is not a good practice to use array.

You can execute the query like

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT permissao_nome FROM sisgrupopermissoes WHERE id_grupo = ".$this->getGid()." AND permissao_nome='".$this->getPermissao()."'");
```

and use mysql_num_rows to check the condition

```
return mysql_num_rows($query)
```

Comment: Don't use *mysql_* anything. Not ever!

Comment: @Strawberry good point but OP is asking about the best approach, it's not about to use MySQL