# How to interrupt function in PHP after some time executing?

Tags: php, algorithm

You can measure execution time in php using:

```
  $inicio = microtime(true);
  ejecutoFunction();
  $fin = microtime(true);
  //here getting the time passed
  $tiempo = $inicio - $fin;
  if($tiempo > $tiempo_limite) {//print it or do something else}
```

however verification happened "post-mortem", method ended before **$tiempo** is calculated, so it doesn't helps like this, because I need something that stops execution if it is taking more than **x** time. For instance,a function that performs a POST request to some URL and it is taking more than 10 sec to respond.

In a very mine fake code would be like this:

```
ejecutoFunction1(){
$timer = 0 seconds;
if $timer reaches 10 seconds{break ejecutoFunction1; ejecutoOtraFunction2();}
start $timer; //timer starts and allow executions until he reaches value 10.

{body of ejecutoFunction1}

}
```

How do I do that in real code in PHP ????
I know it is not easy (for me), but world class minds are reading here. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I measure the speed of code written in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200214/how-can-i-measure-the-speed-of-code-written-in-php)

Comment: See also: http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: Please note that set_time_limits "If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. " and I need to continue execution of script with other functions when limit time is reached.

Comment: I _think_ you want to run your code in a background task that you can control better, right?

Comment: PHP is single-threaded, so there is no way to time-out a function from the outside, or when a blocking operation is happening. Some PHP core or module functions have timeouts that can be set, but those are implemented in C.

Comment: The title of your question is misleading. Your problem is not related to measuring time. Your problem is how to interrupt something if it hasn't finished after a certain amount of time. I guess what you are really looking for is a timeout for the expensive thing your doing inside your function. So we need to know what that function does. I assume it is IO related. So maybe you just need to set a curl timeout or a database connection timeout...

Comment: It is a POST request to some URL and wait for response.

Comment: Also Simon, I edited title and wrote what I want to stop. Thanks.

Comment: Much better title! Well then. Whatever library you use to issue that POST request, most certainly it uses curl under the hood and most probably you'll find a timeout option in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a post call is sent inside, and has to be stopped after sometime, but we need to know that the time limit was reached, solution(and thanks to @muc) would be like this steps:

1-Outside the method: stays like before:

```
  $inicio = microtime(true);
  ejecutoFunction();
  $fin = microtime(true);
  //here getting the time passed
  $tiempo = $inicio - $fin;
  if($tiempo > 10) {echo "Too much time!";}
```

2-inside ejecutoFunction() USE cURL timeout option!!!*(borrowed example)

```
    $html_brand = "www.google.com";
    $tData = '123';
    $ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $html_brand,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $tData,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 11,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $httpCode != 200 ){
    echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n"
        .curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($response)."</pre>";
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks again to @muc. I didn't know about this PHP library.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are not looking for anything like `set_time_limit` as that will kill your entire script. You are looking for a "kill switch" in a loop. It will resemble a "game loop" type structure where it will run the logic inside until a condition is met (i.e. the kill switch).

```php
   // Check if $max number of seconds has elapsed
   function hasReachedTimeout($start, $max = 10) {
      $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
      if ($elapsed > $max) { return true; }
      return false;
   }
   
   function myFunction() {
      $start = microtime(true);
      while (!hasReachedTimeout($start, 10)) {
          doFirstThing();
          if (hasReachedTimeout($start, 10)) { break; }
          doSecondThing();
          if (hasReachedTimeout($start, 10)) { break; }
          doThirdThing();
      }
   }
```

That does a check after each function call just in case and breaks out of the loop. You could also just let the `while` loop stop if after executing everything inside the timeout has exceeded.

Comment: It is not a loop what the function has inside... Actually it is a post call, and I need to cancel the call and execute other function if response takes too much to arrive to me. Also, I think you mean: "while (!hasReachedTimeout(**$startTime**, 10))" right_? I'll give it a try anyway and come back to you... thanks!

Comment: Ah yep, didn't name the variable the same. Fixed it.

Comment: Ok, but see: Your code will execute  doFirstThing() anyway, even if it takes more than 10 seconds, and that is what I want to avoid. However It was a clever answer. Any other solution?

Comment: Are you using cURL or how exactly are you issuing this POST request?

Comment: @Muc I am using simple Js like this:

**document.MethodForm.submit();**

Comment: Oh... I thought you were issuing the POST request from within PHP (To a 3rd party webservice or something)... I don't see any way around it but to isolate the problematic code inside it's own php which you can call from the main one using cURL and setting curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, X);... kind of complicated but should do the trick